# Ordering an NVARCHAR field in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using the below query to order a field in SQL

```
Select Distinct x From t  where c=1 order by x asc
```

X is an nvarchar column but currently the column have the below values

[image]

Is there anyway to order the values to be like this:

> No Prize,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: What rdbms are you working with?

Comment: rdbms what is this?

Comment: tag the sql flavor that you are using...

Comment: @Sora mysql or sql server or oracle?

Comment: check my edit please

Comment: If "no prize" is the only string among numbers >0 then `order by case x when 'No Prize' then 0 else cast(x as int) end asc`

Comment: RDBMS - Relational DataBase Management System.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sql server 2012+ you could use `try_cast`, but you will have to change the `distinct` to a `group by`:

```
SELECT x
FROM t
WHERE c=1
GROUP BY x
ORDER BY Try_Cast(x as int)
```

For older versions you can use union:

```
SELECT x
FROM
(
    SELECT x, CAST(x as int) as sort
    FROM t
    WHERE c = 1
    AND ISNUMERIC(x) = 1

    UNION 

    SELECT x, NULL
    FROM t
    WHERE c = 1
    AND ISNUMERIC(x) = 0
) as distinctX
ORDER BY sort
```

Comment: what if i am using an older version of sql server ?

Comment: @sora let us know your version of sql server

Comment: sql server 2008

Comment: I've edited my answer. In your future questions, please tag the database and version when asking.